# O365 shared mailbox and message center

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

My Office 365 shared mailbox works great, but it keeps receiving emails from Microsoft regarding various updates from Microsoft 364 Message Center. The latest was about "Yammer" losing TLS 1.0 support... and that goes to a shared mailbox named accounting@company.xyz

How can I end this behaviour?

p.s. All I could find so far were suggestions to give the user admin rights in the message centre, so the user can then can log in and opt-out of those messages. But shared mailbox is not a real user, and is not supposed to log in anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, my shared mailbox couldn't subscribe these update message automatically, so I think your issue may be related to any setting in your admin center or there may be any redirect rules in your organization.
Actually, We could find the subcribe address on the end of messages like below:[image].

If it's an admin address in your organization, you could try to check his preference setting in message center:
[image]

Comment: subscribe address is the same as shared mailbox address. and when I go to message center with my own user, then there are are no other email addresses, it is unchecked. So I think shared mailbox has somehow subscribed to those messages itself.

Comment: Was this shared mailbox converted from a user mailbox?
By the way, if you wouldn't like to log in this mailbox, as an workaround, maybe you could block these message via server rule: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/use-transport-rules-to-configure-bulk-email-filtering?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: no, it was not converted. recently and originally created like this. will try your workaround.

Comment: Could it work for you?